# Storing an unspecified range of numbers into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a program that receives an array of integers with an unspecified lenght. In other words the length is decided by how many integers the user enters, but the user does not get the opportunity to enter how many integers the array will contain, before storing any integers. The maximum number of integers that can be stored is 100. If a negative number is entered, this signifies the end of the array, and this negative value should not be stored. The program should also calculate the average of the integers that are stored.

All of this is extremely easy as long as the lenght of the array is specified. I can't figure out how to stop reading integers when a negative number is entered, and also i can't figure out how to not store the negative number.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class AnalyzeScores {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double sum = 0, average = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int scores[] = new int[100];

        System.out.println("Enter the scores: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {

            scores[i] = input.nextInt(); 

            if (input.nextInt() < 0) {
                i--; // Remove the last input if negative
                break; // Exit the loop
            }

            sum += scores[i];

            average = sum / (i + 1);

        }

        System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);

        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);

    }
 }
```

The break statement works for exiting the loop when a negative is entered, but the sum and average are totally wrong. For example, the entered number 1 2 3 4 5 -1, gives a sum = 4, and average = 2.

I hope the question is not considered stupid, and I will appreciate any help!

Comment: In your `for-loop` use : 'if(scores[i]<0) {break;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the for loop you called two times `input.nextInt();` but stored only the first `int` into `scores[i]`. Hence the first integer is stored into `scores[]` but the second one is skipped. For example, if the inputs are

> 1 2 3 4 5 -1

then,

- `scores[0]` gets `1` by calling `input.nextInt();`.
- The next call of `input.nextInt()` inside the `if` statement consume `2`.
- `sum` becomes `0 + 1 = 1`.
- Loop iterates and `scores[1]` gets `3` (instead of `2` what you are expecting).
- and similarly `4` got consumed inside the `if`.
- `sum` becomes `1 + 3 = 4`.
- In the next iteration of loop, `scores[2]` gets `5`.
- `input.nextInt()` inside the `if` statement consume `-1` and this time `if` block find the `true` path and loop `breaks`.
- hence `sum` remains `4`.

Change the following:

```
if (input.nextInt() < 0) {
    i--; // Remove the last input if negative
    break; // Exit the loop
}
```

to:

```
if (scores[i] < 0) {
    break; // Exit the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to make a program that receives an array of integers with
>   an unspecified lenght. In other words the length is decided by how
>   many integers the user enters, but the user does not get the
>   opportunity to enter how many integers the array will contain, before
>   storing any integers.

**Better use `ArrayList` in this case, if array length is not pre-defined**

> The maximum number of integers that can be stored is 100

**Keep checking for size, break for negative number or elements more than 100**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        double sum = 0, average = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter the scores: ");
        int i = 0;
        int number = 0;
        while (number >= 0 && scores.size()<=100) {
            number = input.nextInt();
            if (number >= 0) {
                scores.add(number);
                sum += number;
                average = sum / (scores.size());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
    }
```

**output**

```
Enter the scores: 
1
2
3
4
5
-1
Sum is 15.0
Average is: 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question right. If you want to introduce an infinite number of integers; use `List`type for this case. It's more efficient for dynamic entry as you're asking for (instead `array` type).

Next, if you want to control negative or positive numbers introduced; make use of an `if`condition. For example:

```
if(number < 0){

    System.out.println("Introduce other number.");

}else{

*/your code for introducing a number goes here*/

}
```